# Unet Runtime Execution stop with warning message

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a u-net to mask the image data with its labels. Data management part in code went well. Here i am struggling with this code when i run unet.py. Code execute and throw warning and further process stop without getting into results. wanted to know if its library version issue? Didnt find anything similar to it. In the later line i have debugged, Still not giving out any clue. The code execution stops at "***Using TensorFlow backend***". without giving any error and does proceed to training the model and saving model phase. All the directory structure has been checked and in correct order.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img
import cv2
from data import *


class myUnet(object):
def __init__(self, img_rows=512, img_cols=512):
    self.img_rows = img_rows
    self.img_cols = img_cols

def load_data(self):
    mydata = dataProcess(self.img_rows, self.img_cols)
    imgs_train, imgs_mask_train = mydata.load_train_data()
    imgs_test = mydata.load_test_data()
    return imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, imgs_test

    def get_unet(self):
    inputs = Input((self.img_rows, self.img_cols, 3))

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',                                                                      kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
    # print(conv1)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    print ("conv1 shape:", conv1.shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    print ("conv1 shape:", conv1.shape)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    print ("pool1 shape:", pool1.shape)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',   kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
    print ("conv2 shape:", conv2.shape)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    print ("conv2 shape:", conv2.shape)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    print ("pool2 shape:", pool2.shape)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
    print ("conv3 shape:", conv3.shape)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    print ("conv3 shape:", conv3.shape)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    print ("pool3 shape:", pool3.shape)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    up6 = BatchNormalization()(up6)
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)
    print(up6)
    print(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)
    print(conv6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)
    print(conv6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))
    up7 = BatchNormalization()(up7)
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)
    print(up7)
    print(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    print(conv7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)
    print(conv7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))
    up8 = BatchNormalization()(up8)
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))
    up9 = BatchNormalization()(up9)
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)
    print(up9)
    print(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    print(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    print(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    print ("conv9 shape:", conv9.shape)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)
    print(conv10)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def train(self):
    print("loading data")
    imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, imgs_test = self.load_data()
    print("loading data done")
    model = self.get_unet()
    print("got unet")
    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet.hdf5', monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    print('Fitting model...')
    model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=4, epochs=100, verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

    print('predict test data')
    imgs_mask_test = model.predict(imgs_test, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
    np.save('./data/results/imgs_mask_test.npy', imgs_mask_test)

def save_img(self):
    print("array to image")
    imgs = np.load('./data/results/imgs_mask_test.npy')
    piclist = []
    for line in open("./data/results/pic.txt"):
        line = line.strip()
        picname = line.split('/')[-1]
        piclist.append(picname)
    print(len(piclist))
    for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
        path = "./data/results/" + piclist[i]
        img = imgs[i]
        img = array_to_img(img)
        img.save(path)
        cv_pic = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        cv_pic = cv2.resize(cv_pic,(1918,1280),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        binary, cv_save = cv2.threshold(cv_pic, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite(path, cv_save)

def load_model_weights(self, model):
    model.load_weights('./data/unet.hdf5')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("going to create model")
    myunet = myUnet()
    print("model created.. going to retreive model")
    model = myunet.get_unet()
    # model.summary()
    # plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
    # myunet.load_model_weights(model)
    print("train model")
    myunet.train()
    print("save model")
    myunet.save_img()

WARNING:tensorflow:From unet.py:4: The name tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU   is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From unet.py:4: The name tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM instead.

Using TensorFlow backend.
```

Comment: What makes you think it has stopped?

Comment: I have debugged the all the code. Everything fine. Yet it still does not start training and generate the weights .h5 file

Comment: Where should it save the file? Is it possibly training, but very slowly? Sometimes it can take awhile to load data. There are a lot of unknowns here.

Comment: Files saves inside results folder in this case.  if you could only see below if__name__=="__main__" the print("going to create model") does not even print. It does process after  "Using TensorFlow backend". The process totally stops here.

Comment: So you're not gettting past the import statements? Stop importing everything.

Comment: Yes it worked! Stopped importing everything. Running fine now! Thanks